# Unable to start virgo-tomcat server under Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, eclipse-virgo

I'm unable to start **virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.4.RELEASE** under cygwin-64bit on Windows 7. It's converting paths properly, but still getting below error:

> !SESSION Fri Aug 05 15:51:09 IST 2016
>   ------------------------------------------ !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2016-08-05 15:51:09.520 !MESSAGE
>   Exception launching the Eclipse Platform: !STACK
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

I downloaded latest virgo-tomcat server from

https://eclipse.org/virgo/download/

and running **startup.sh** inside cygwin. I added some echo statements in **dmk.sh** file to find out what's going on which are giving below outputs:

```
cygwin value: true
cygwin CLASSPATH INSIDE CYGWIN TRUE CONDITION***: :/home/pg/virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.4.RELEASE/lib/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120308-1358.jar:/home/pg/virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.4.RELEASE/lib/org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.equinox.extensions_3.6.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/pg/virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.4.RELEASE/lib/org.eclipse.virgo.nano.authentication_3.6.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/pg/virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.4.RELEASE/lib/org.eclipse.virgo.nano.shutdown_3.6.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/pg/virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.4.RELEASE/lib/org.eclipse.virgo.util.env_3.6.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/pg/virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.4.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar:/home/pg/virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.4.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.console.ssh_1.0.0.v20120430-1356.jar

cygwin CLASSPATH OUTSIDE IF: .;D:\Softwares\cygwin64\home\myuser\local_setup\virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.4.RELEASE\lib\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120308-1358.jar;D:\Softwares\cygwin64\home\myuser\local_setup\virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.4.RELEASE\lib\org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.equinox.extensions_3.6.4.RELEASE.jar;D:\Softwares\cygwin64\home\myuser\local_setup\virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.4.RELEASE\lib\org.eclipse.virgo.nano.authentication_3.6.4.RELEASE.jar;D:\Softwares\cygwin64\home\myuser\local_setup\virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.4.RELEASE\lib\org.eclipse.virgo.nano.shutdown_3.6.4.RELEASE.jar;D:\Softwares\cygwin64\home\myuser\local_setup\virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.4.RELEASE\lib\org.eclipse.virgo.util.env_3.6.4.RELEASE.jar;D:\Softwares\cygwin64\home\myuser\local_setup\virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.4.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar;D:\Softwares\cygwin64\home\myuser\local_setup\virgo-tomcat-server-3.6.4.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.console.ssh_1.0.0.v20120430-1356.jar
cygwin JAVA_HOME: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/Java/JDK17~1.0_7
cygwin JAVA_EXECUTABLE: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/Java/JDK17~1.0_7/bin/java
cygwin JAVA_OPTS:  -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Looks like classpath is fine. But I can't find out what's wrong and why I'm getting that error.

I tried starting normal tomcat under Cygwin, which is working fine but I'm unable to start virgo-tomcat.

Comment: Virgo has problems with **long** file paths [Bug 319270 - Long file paths make Virgo unusable for my target audience](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=319270). Did you try to install Virgo as close to root as possible?

Comment: @FlorianWaibel Will check and let you know.

Comment: @FlorianWaibel Still not working.. :(